# Text pattern search and match

Tags: similarities

So the question, I hope, is simple...

I have 800 unique strings and I need to find, select and classify each one of them from a set of 30000 plus strings... ok, until there no problem. The trick is that each one of those 30thousand+ strings can have special characters in the string and I need to find and select those that are similar to the 800 unique ones

As for example, I have a unique string "AbCdef 23_3 zexy" and in the huge set of strings I can find things like "AbCde%f 23_3 zexy" or "AbCdef 23 3 zexy" or "AbCdef 23-3 zexy" or "AbCdef 23_3° zexy¬" all of them accepted as part of the group that corresponds to "AbCdef 23_3 zexy" the original one

I have tried some tools but cannot find the right way to classify the groups.

Some idea about tools or code to be used??

Comment: Have you heard of levenshtein distance?

Comment: This is a job for [Regular Expressions](https://xkcd.com/208/). In perl or R or the language of your choice, just remove all the "special characters" compressing the strings to a canonical form of just letters and numbers. Globally replacing this: `[\W\s_]` with nothing should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use Python to do this by replacing the target string of each special character. As below, if you have special characters like '%', then you can load your strings in a text file, remove them with `filedata.replace` as shown, with your new strings being outputted into a new text file. Once you have eliminated all special characters, you can then compare which ones still do not correspond to the group after removing them.

`# Read in the file
with open('file.txt', 'r') as file :
  filedata = file.read()`

`# Replace the target string
filedata = filedata.replace('%', '')
filedata = filedata.replace('°', '')`

`# Write the file out again
with open('file2.txt', 'w') as file:
  file.write(filedata)`